# Why is this ExecuteQuery causing InvalidCastException?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, casting

I get InvalidCastException when I call First() at the last line. Can anyone tell me why?

```
static bool TableExists(string tableNameAndSchema) 
{
    string checkTable =
        String.Format(
        "IF OBJECT_ID('{0}', 'U') IS NOT NULL SELECT 'true' ELSE SELECT 'false'",
        tableNameAndSchema);            

    var result = db.ExecuteQuery<bool>(checkTable);
    return result.First();
}
```

Comment: Try `IF OBJECT_ID('{0}', 'U') IS NOT NULL SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0`

Comment: Did you check the type of `result`?

Comment: You should also watch out for SQL injection in that code.

Comment: @EbenRoux I would post that as an answer.

Comment: sorry that did not work either - I still get the InvalidCastException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the following two formats work properly. The core of the challenge appears to be what type is returned by ExecuteQuery.

SELECT 'true' actually returns a string and not a bool - thus the ExecuteQuery result variable also has to be string (and not bool) if using that format

And when using SELECT 1 as suggested by @Eben Roux and @Anders Abel, then the ExecuteQuery result variable has to be int (and not bool)

```
static bool TableExists(string tableNameAndSchema)
{
    string checkTable =
        String.Format(
        "IF OBJECT_ID('{0}', 'U') IS NOT NULL SELECT 'true' ELSE SELECT 'false'",
        tableNameAndSchema);

    IEnumerable<string> result = db.ExecuteQuery<string>(checkTable);
    return Convert.ToBoolean(result.First());
}

static bool TableExists2(string tableNameAndSchema)
{
    string checkTable =
        String.Format(
        "IF OBJECT_ID('{0}', 'U') IS NOT NULL SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0",
        tableNameAndSchema);

    IEnumerable<int> result = db.ExecuteQuery<int>(checkTable);
    return Convert.ToBoolean(result.First());
}
```

Thanks to @Eben Roux and @Anders Abel whose answers pointed me toward the final solution(s) - (I marked your answers as useful as they steered me in the right direction to get the final answer - thanks guys :) )

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('{0}', 'U') IS NOT NULL SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0
```

The thing is that the result is a string and the cast is, obviously, failing.  if you could do a `Convert.ToBool("true|false")` it would work.

Comment: sorry that did not work either - I still get the InvalidCastException

Comment: I only noticed where your exception is throwing now.  What is the type of result.First()?

Comment: Thanks Eben. Your and Anders answers (I think you both posted at the same time) got me pointed in the right direction for the final answer so I marked your answer as useful.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL bit data type corresponds to .NET's `bool`. It uses `1` and `0` for true and false values. Try changing your code to:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('{0}', 'U') IS NOT NULL SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0
```

Comment: Thanks Anders. Your and Eben's answers (I think you both posted at the same time) got me pointed in the right direction for the final answer so I marked your answer as useful.